# Hive Use of Case with may "or" "and"

Tags: sql, validation, hive, case, hiveql

Hi I have a table with dispositionid and notes columns.

example:

```
disposition    notetext
call           abc
email          zyx
voice mail     opq
```

my current query

```
select
CASE WHEN (instr(n.notetext,'xyz')>=1) OR (instr(n.notetext,'opq')>=1) OR (instr(n.notetext,'abc')>=1) OR (instr(n.notetext,'trs')>=1) OR (instr(n.notetext,'jhf')>=1) 
AND dispocition IN ('call','email','voice mail','left message') then 1 else 0 as column1
from table1
```

but looks like the query is counting the "and" statement just with the last "or" validation.

I need that the "and" statement counts for every case of or statement.

Regards

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: I need my validation request 2 things 1st the disposition could be into the list "IN ('call','email'.....  2nd AND the notetext (string) have inside one of the special words inside like 'xyz' or 'opq'.etc...

Comment: . . The explanation belongs in the *question* not in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You want to wrap the `OR` clauses with a parenthesis:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN ( ( INSTR(n.notetext, 'xyz') >= 1 ) 
                 OR ( INSTR(n.notetext, 'opq') >= 1 ) 
                 OR ( INSTR(n.notetext, 'abc') >= 1 ) 
                 OR ( INSTR(n.notetext, 'trs') >= 1 ) 
                 OR ( INSTR(n.notetext, 'jhf') >= 1 ) ) 
              AND disposition IN ( 'call', 'email', 'voice mail', 'left message') 
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0 
       END AS column1 
FROM   table1 n
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of all `instr` checks you can use single `RLIKE` with OR in regexp (`|`):

```
select
      CASE WHEN n.notetext rlike ('xyz|opq|abc|trs|jhf') 
                AND n.dispocition IN ('call','email','voice mail','left message') 
           THEN 1 
           ELSE 0 
       END as column1
from table1 n
```